# No Windows 7 repair option after system upgrade

Tags: windows-7, boot, system-restore

I upgraded my motherboard, CPU and RAM yesterday but my system won't boot anymore. I've got Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

I expected to run into some sort of boot problems and created a bootable installation USB stick before upgrading. But when I run the setup routine, it goes straight to the new installation setup, with no repair this computer option.

Can anyone here offer some advice on this? I have quite a lot of programs installed and don't want to have to reinstall everything, if humanly possible.

Comment: It's probably because the installation is not being recognised. You will need to use a diagnostic disc, such as [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) or a Linux Live CD, to check out the status of your partitions.

Comment: I forgot to say, I've another Windows 7 x64 pc as well if its possible to repair the drive using this.

Comment: Yes, if you take the disc out and have an external USB cradle. It might be worth first making sure that you can get into repair mode on the other PC, where you know the system is intact (you will be able to abort before doing anything) - I don't know if all installation discs have the repair option.

Comment: Thanks for the input AFH. I've gotten to the point now where Win7 starts and goes into a boot loop. Back in XP days I would've simply run an in-place non-destructive reinstall of Windows and then installed all the drivers once it booted to the desktop. This seems to be impossible in Win7. I've tried the same installation media (usb stick) on the working pc and it gives me the option to repair on its own hdd, but not on the affected one.

Comment: Oh, I can get the startup repair on Windows bootup now. And I can now get the dos prompt. I can't boot to safe mode either. I've rebuilt the BCD but that doesn't help, so I suspect its not a BCD issue. Maybe the iastor drivers for the new board need installed?

Comment: The question begins "I upgraded my motherboard, CPU and RAM ...", and it said that before any edits. What needs updating?

Comment: Sorry Ramhound, AFH is correct. I'll be doing more on this tomorrow so I'll post an update then. Incidentally, what will I be looking for with Hiren's? As Win7 is now bootable, if not booting, I take it that the partition is active.

Comment: Hiren allows you to run disc and partition checks. You can also mount partitions and even run programs on them, provided they are not heavily dependent on registry entries and other settings (which Hiren won't have). You can also make a complete disc back-up, which is essential before you start making changes. What you mean by "Win7 is bootable"? Does it give you the boot selection screen (after F8, if necessary)? If you can't get further, then you have verified the boot partition, but not the Windows partition.